# How do I select rows within a group of rows whose Amounts do not cancel each other out?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Given a number of rows similar to the ones in the following temp table:

```
TransactionId | AccountsDocumentLineId | Amount
-------------   ----------------------   ------
52345           12345                    -15.79
52346           12345                    15.79
52347           12345                    -15.79
52348           22222                    -6.34
52349           22222                    6.34
52350           22222                    6.34
52351           22222                    -6.34
52352           22222                    -8.76
52353           22222                    10.49
```

how do I ensure any rows that cancel each other out (sum to zero) with the *same* `AccountsDocumentLineId` are removed and only ones that have no more matching rows that they can be paired with are left?

So, in the above example, the row with `TransactionId` = `52345` (*or* `52347`) would be left (since the `-15.79` and `15.79` would cancel each other out).

Similarly, the rows with `TransactionId` = `52352` and `52353` would remain (since the two pairs of `-6.34` and `6.34` would cancel each other out).

So, we would get the following end result:

```
TransactionId | AccountsDocumentLineId | Amount
-------------   ----------------------   ------
52347           12345                    -15.79
52352           22222                    -8.76
52353           22222                    10.49
```

Note: I've stripped out all the unnecessary detail (more columns and plenty more rows) to simply show the issue at hand.

Some options I've played with are:-

- Summing up all the `Amount`s within a group of `AccountDocumentLineId`s and seeing which row matches the balance but that would only deal with the first example (where there's only one row remaining) and *not* the second one where there are two rows that need to remain (so no easy of splitting one value to give the two rows)
- Going through each entry within a group of `AccountDocumentLineId`s and if a match is found delete *both* counterparts; **I think this one would work** although not sure how to go about doing it in SQL?

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/899e4/1)

UPDATE: Added [complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14581570/1578713) based on [Bulat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14525084/1578713).

Comment: What have you tried? Post some working queries, does not matter if the result is incorrect, is a starting point and maybe you are not far from the solution.

Comment: Thanks, will do. I should have added at least one but have tried so many dodgy solutions and am rather embarrassed looking at the ones I have.

Comment: Do you want to remove transactions where there is a corresponding pair only e.g. 10 and -10, or you need to remove any matching transactions, e.g. 10 and -4 and -6?

Comment: Are you wanting to perform a SELECT or a DELETE ?  Forgive me but your question is ambiguous on that.

Comment: Also it will be great to have sqlfiddle for this

Comment: Thanks, guys, for your questions. It's actually `DELETE` I'm after but thought I'd at least try and get the `SELECT` right then work on the `DELETE`.

Comment: @Bulat: Your question is good and I forgot to mention that. To begin with, I'm assuming the matches will be like for like. I didn't want to complicate things further so I'm leaving that possibility for another day!

Comment: @iDevelApp Ok, you should try to do simple INNER JOIN then on t1.Amount = (-)t2.Amount. That will give you all possible matches for starters.  Once you have that, you will need to add NOT EXISTS clause to filter out duplicate matches, e.g. if you have 10, 10, -10, for one doc line.

Comment: @Bulat - yes but there is the flipside of that which is that 2 debits could equal one credit, and vice versa.  I am sure that an allocation stored procedure is the only way - not a trivial task by any means.

Comment: Look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520326/how-do-i-select-rows-within-a-group-of-rows-whose-amounts-do-not-cancel-each-oth/35788690#35788690

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run this code many times (for example while it affects more then 0 records):

```
WITH Matches AS
(
SELECT t1 = t1. TransactionId, t2 = t2.TransactionId, 
  a1 = t1.Amount, a2 = t2.Amount, t1.AccountsDocumentLineId
FROM  Transactions t1 
    INNER JOIN Transactions t2 
        ON t1.AccountsDocumentLineId = t2.AccountsDocumentLineId
           AND t1.Amount = -t2.Amount 
           AND t1.TransactionId < t2.TransactionId 
)
DELETE FROM Transactions
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM Matches m1
WHERE Transactions.TransactionId IN(m1.t1,m1.t2)
  AND NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT * FROM Matches m2
  WHERE  abs(m1.a1) = abs(m2.a1) 
     AND m1.AccountsDocumentLineId = m2.AccountsDocumentLineId
     AND (
         (m2.t1 > m1.t1 AND m2.t2 <= m1.t2)  
      OR (m2.t2 < m1.t2 AND (m2.t1 >= m1.t1))
      OR m2.t1 = m1.t2
     ) 
 )
);
```

Comment: Excellent work, @Bulat, this appears to do exactly what I'm after. I've wrapped this around a very simple loop and this deals with all the matching pairs.

Comment: @iDevelApp great and you are welcome ) it will be good to see your wrapping code as well, just to make it complete.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is straightforward

```
DELETE FROM MYTABLE WHERE AccountsDocumentLineId IN
  (SELECT AccountsDocumentLineId from MYTABLE 
   GROUP BY AccountsDocumentLineId 
   HAVING SUM(Amount) <> 0)
```

But you may find you have some fettling to do to cope with precision errors.

That should leave you with only unbalanced accounts. From there you will have to (I think) create a stored procedure to 'allocate' debits to credits.  From your data sample it seems likely that the transaction id is nicely ordered, so that should help.

Comment: Thanks @Hugh, +1 for your effort. Sorry, I should have made clear that I already have that covered and my SQL for that is pretty much the same as what you've put: `DELETE FROM #RemainingLedgerEntries WHERE TransactionId IN (SELECT TransactionId FROM #RemainingLedgerEntries WHERE AccountsDocumentLineId IN (SELECT AccountsDocumentLineId FROM 
#RemainingLedgerEntries GROUP BY AccountsDocumentLineId HAVING ABS(SUM(Amount)) = 0))`, where `#RemainingLedgerEntries` is the temp table.

Comment: @iDevelApp - I have done this kind of work before and I know you have quite a challenge facing you.  It would be too good to be true if you went to the business and they agreed you can aggregate all previous transactions into a single 'BroughtForward' transaction ... You should ask if you can because there is a world of hurt in this little chestnut :)

Comment: Thanks, @Hugh, for the tip and I know what you mean! You haven't seen the rest of the task at hand; believe it or not, this is the least of my worries at the minute...!

Answer (score 0):

In response to Bulat's request for my wrapped code, I'm submitting it here (and for the benefit of others):

```
DECLARE 
      @SequenceStart INT = 0,
      @SequenceEnd INT = 10 -- Just to be on the safe side, though unlikely for there to be 10 matching pairs for the same AccountsDocumentLineId

STARTLOOP:
    SET
        @SequenceStart = @SequenceStart+1   
    ;
    WITH Matches AS
    (
        SELECT
            L1 = L1.TransactionId, L2 = L2.TransactionId,
            A1 = L1.Amount, A2 = L2.Amount, L1.AccountsDocumentLineId
        FROM
            #RemainingLedgerEntries L1
            INNER JOIN #RemainingLedgerEntries L2
                ON L1.AccountsDocumentLineId = L2.AccountsDocumentLineId
                AND L1.Amount*-1 = L2.Amount
                AND L1.TransactionId < L2.TransactionId
    )
    DELETE FROM
        #RemainingLedgerEntries
    WHERE
        EXISTS
        (
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                Matches M1
            WHERE
                #RemainingLedgerEntries.TransactionId IN (M1.L1, M1.L2)
            AND NOT EXISTS
            (
                SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    Matches M2
                WHERE
                    ABS(M1.A1) = ABS(M2.A1) 
                AND M1.AccountsDocumentLineId = M2.AccountsDocumentLineId
                AND
                (
                    (M2.L1 > M1.L1 AND M2.L2 <= M1.L2)  
                    OR (M2.L2 < M1.L2 AND (M2.L1 >= M1.L1))
                    OR M2.L1 = M1.L2
                ) 
            )
        )

    IF @SequenceStart >= @SequenceEnd
        GOTO ENDTASK

    GOTO STARTLOOP

ENDTASK:
```

Comment: cool, thanks. I though you used @@ROWCOUNT to do `WHILE` loop while it is greater than zero.

Comment: @Bulat, yeah, I'm sure it's not the best solution but it was the quickest one and did the job!

Comment: sure ) I was just curious whether it will work with ROWCOUNT. no worries, your solution is also fine.